# Linux iptables redirect

Tags: linux, iptables

I am an ISP and I need to suspend with a message the clients who didn't pay. For every web page they access they have to see "suspended" (port 80) and all the other ports need to be closed. How can I accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: Looks a lot like homework.  Were you actually an ISP you'd know how to use Google.

Answer (score 1):

you set up apache with default web-host hosting whatever information you want to pass.

you tell apache to show that message for any request:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

you redirect client's [10.1.2.3] traffic to your apache [i assume it runs on your router]:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 10.1.2.3 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to localhost:80
```